# Autogenerated Many-to-Many Table, add a new record to it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I add a record into the autogenerated table "RelativesPatients" and link them together when I have an object from both tables using Entity Framework?

```
public ActionResult CreateConnection() {     
    var relative = _context.Relatives.Single(r => r.Id == viewModel.RelativeId);
    var patient = _context.Patients.Single(p => p.Id == viewModel.PatientId);

    patient.Relatives.Add(relative); 
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

public class Relative
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Relative> Relatives { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That looks correct. Are you seeing an error? Another possible way to do it: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Comment: It gives me Null reference exception for some reason on patient.Relatives.Add(relative); But I've the objects above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a constructor for your collections:

```
public class Relative
{
    public Relative()
    {
        Patients = new Collection<Patient>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public Patient()
    {
        Relatives  = new Collection<Relative>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Relative> Relatives { get; set; }
}
```

or you can new them up manually:

```
patient.Relatives = new Collection<Relative>();
patient.Relatives.Add(relative);
```